# I can't bind events to elements

Tags: javascript

```js
const color = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'navy', 'purple'];
let a = [];
for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
  a[i] = document.createElement("input");
  a[i].type = 'button';
  a[i].id = 'b' + (i + 1);
  a[i].value = color[i];
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('color');
  })
  document.body.appendChild(a[i]);
  document.body.innerHTML += "<br>"
  console.log(a[0].innerHTML);
}
```

It seems that the listener is not getting bound despite the `addEventListener`. What is the problem?

Comment: It seems you're missing ";" in the line of adding the event listener. Try adding a semi-colon there (in the line above: "document.body,appendChild(a[i]);"). Also, be sure to add the HTML so we can be more helpful.. it might have something do to with that. Try doing this trough [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and simply share the link, that's another easier method. Also, it is common to be more specific about your problem when asking questions here..

Comment: I don't think you can add an event listener to a button before it has been appended to the body, you need to add event listeners after the elements have been added to the DOM.

Comment: Please remember we're on a Question & Answer site. Questions should have enough detail that the volunteers here can help you, and questions should be useful to the next developer with a similar issue.

Comment: @stealththeninja There are enough details in the question, though. There's a fully working code to reproduce the problem, and a minimalistic, but full explanation of the problem ...

Comment: @Lloyd You can indeed add a listener to an element before appending the element to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for you guys comments. @stealththeninja Sorry this is my first question to use stackoverflow. Please understand my question skill :)

Comment: @RecklessEngineer I'm trying to make code with pureJS :)  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, when concatenating with the `innerHTML` of a container (for example, with your `document.body.innerHTML += "<br>"`), the container will be *emptied* and then re-parsed with the new HTML string. If you previously attached a listener to an element in the container, that listener will not be in the HTML string, so it will not transfer over to the *new* element in the same position.

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('#somediv');
document.body.innerHTML += '';
const div2 = document.querySelector('#somediv');

console.log(div1 === div2);
// False, the container's contents were re-parsed, the new div is different!
```

```html
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

Either append your `br` using the same `appendChild` method you're using for the `a[i]`:

```js
const color = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'navy', 'purple'];
let a = [];
for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
  a[i] = document.createElement("input");
  a[i].type = 'button';
  a[i].id = 'b' + (i + 1);
  a[i].value = color[i];
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('color');
  })
  document.body.appendChild(a[i]);
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

Or use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead, which can act similarly to `.innerHTML +=`, but unlike `.innerHTML +=`, does *not* re-create all elements in the container:

```js
const color = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'navy', 'purple'];
let a = [];
for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
  a[i] = document.createElement("input");
  a[i].type = 'button';
  a[i].id = 'b' + (i + 1);
  a[i].value = color[i];
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('color');
  })
  document.body.appendChild(a[i]);
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Oh Thanks!!  I can get new information about your advice. I've never heard about that

Answer (score 0):

```
const color = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'navy', 'purple'];
let a = [];
for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
 a[i] = document.createElement("input");
 a[i].type = 'button';
 a[i].id = 'b' + (i + 1);
 a[i].value = color[i];
 document.body.appendChild(a[i]);
 document.body.innerHTML += "<br>"
 console.log(a[0].innerHTML);
 }
for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
   var el = document.getElementById("b" + (i + 1)) ;
   console.log(el)
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
   alert('color');
  })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3zw0a1tx/